# Getting measured height in Android Studio doesn't work properly

Tags: android, android-listview, height, scrollable

I have multiple list views inside a scrollable view, so I used a function that computes the height of a list view and sets it so the list view is not scrollable anymore.

```
public static void setHeightListView(ListView listView) {

    Adapter adapter = listView.getAdapter();

    int UNBOUNDED = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

    int height = listView.getDividerHeight() * (listView.getCount() - 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); ++i) {
        View child = adapter.getView(i, null, listView);
        child.measure(UNBOUNDED, UNBOUNDED);
        height += child.getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams listViewParams = listView.getLayoutParams();
    listViewParams.height = height;
    listView.requestLayout();
}
```

This function has worked fine so far, but it doesn't compute the correct height for this in getView() in my adapter:

```
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_frame_no_rounded_corners, null);
```

activity_frame_no_rounded_corners.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:background="@drawable/textview_white">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview_modify"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_remove_circle_24" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_key"
                android:text="Key"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:padding="7dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Vlue"/>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/vertical_bar_devider"
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#dcdcdc"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edittext_value"
                android:text="Value"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:padding="7dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.6"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Value"
                android:background="@drawable/textview_white"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_baseline_arrow_forward_ios_24_gray"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

If I use a different xml then it computes the right height. Also, if I remove the weight from the views it also computes the right height (but I need the weight for alignment, I couldn't find a way around it).

You can see in the Screenshot the different list views that I have (one for the names, one for the dob, one for the grade, one for the email, one for the gmc no, one for the specialities).

For testing purposes, they do not have any margins, so they should be one right after the other.
As you can see, the height of the email list view is computed correctly, but my function fails for the rest of the lists. If I change "GMC Number" to "Email" then the function computes the right height for the gmc no list view as well (idk why, it's just an observation).

[image: Screenshot 1]

I guess my problem has something to do with the weight, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Actually, the problem is about structure. You shouldn't put multiple ListView inside a ScrollView. Instead, use a RecyclerView with multiple view-types. So, trying to find a solution to this problem is not recommended.

Comment: I see, thank you! I will definitely modify that in the future, but atm it would be nice to have an easier fix for my problem

Comment: @aminography thank you for the comment, I decided to switch my code to RecyclerView and everything is perfect now!

Comment: You're welcome :) Now everything is extensible and maintainable.